# Write a program that counts the number of occurrences of "11" in an input sequence of zeros and ones in PYTHON3

Tags: python-3.x, probability, probability-theory

Suppose I enter a list like [0,0,1,1,1,0], the program should print 2. I wrote a simple program like this:

```
def count11(seq):
    n= len(seq)
    print (n)
    cnt=0
    #i=0;
    print(cnt) 
    #print(i) 
    for i in range (0,n):
        if(seq[i] and seq[i+1]==1):
            cnt+=1;
            #i+=1;
    return cnt    
          
print(count11([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))
```

But this condition will not work at extremes. like if len(seq)=5 and at i=4 the loop will show an error.
Can you please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the fix not obvious?

Comment: It might be obvious. But I am not able to find the obvious fix

Comment: So if you work on your roof and you always take five steps towards the edge and the fifth step always makes you fall off the roof, do you also go to a home improvement forum and ask what to do, instead of simply *not* taking that fifth step and only doing four? This is ridiculous.

Comment: a hint: you can find the  start index of the pattern(11) with KMP algorithm

Comment: @archzi And you can also buy a Mercedes to visit your neighbor who lives 10 meters away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fix some problem

```py
def count11(seq):
    n = len(seq)
    print(n)
    cnt = 0
    # i=0;
    print(cnt)
    # print(i) 
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        if seq[i] == 1 and seq[i + 1] == 1:
            cnt += 1
            # i+=1;
    return cnt


print(count11([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]))
```